# Optimizing PostgreSQL Query

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I need help optimizing this PostgreSQL Query. I've already created some indexes but the only index being used is "cp_campaign_task_ap_index".

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM campaign_phones 
INNER JOIN campaigns ON campaigns.id = campaign_phones.campaign_id 
INNER JOIN campaign_ports ON campaign_ports.campaign_id = campaigns.id 
WHERE campaign_phones.task_id IS NULL 
AND campaign_phones.assigned_port = 2 
AND (campaigns.auto_start IS TRUE) 
AND (campaigns.starts_at_date::date <= '2018-07-08' 
AND campaigns.ends_at_date::date >= '2018-07-08') 
AND (campaign_ports.gateway_port_id = 611) 
AND (campaign_ports.op_mode != 1) 
ORDER BY campaigns.last_sent_at ASC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 1;`
```

The output of the command is:

```
Limit  (cost=26031.86..26031.87 rows=1 width=475) (actual time=2335.421..2335.421 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Sort  (cost=26031.86..26047.26 rows=6158 width=475) (actual time=2335.419..2335.419 rows=1 loops=1)
    Sort Key: campaigns.last_sent_at NULLS FIRST
    Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=136.10..26001.07 rows=6158 width=475) (actual time=1.176..1510.276 rows=36666 loops=1)
            Join Filter: (campaigns.id = campaign_phones.campaign_id)
            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..28.28 rows=2 width=218) (actual time=0.163..0.435 rows=4 loops=1)
                Join Filter: (campaigns.id = campaign_ports.campaign_id)
                Rows Removed by Join Filter: 113
                ->  Seq Scan on campaign_ports  (cost=0.00..21.48 rows=9 width=55) (actual time=0.017..0.318 rows=9 loops=1)
                        Filter: ((op_mode <> 1) AND (gateway_port_id = 611))
                        Rows Removed by Filter: 823
                ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..5.74 rows=8 width=163) (actual time=0.001..0.008 rows=13 loops=9)
                    ->  Seq Scan on campaigns  (cost=0.00..5.70 rows=8 width=163) (actual time=0.011..0.050 rows=13 loops=1)
                        Filter: ((auto_start IS TRUE) AND ((starts_at_date)::date <= '2018-07-08'::date) AND ((ends_at_date)::date >= '2018-07-08'::date))
                        Rows Removed by Filter: 22
            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on campaign_phones  (cost=136.10..12931.82 rows=4366 width=249) (actual time=43.079..302.895 rows=9166 loops=4)
                Recheck Cond: ((campaign_id = campaign_ports.campaign_id) AND (task_id IS NULL) AND (assigned_port = 2))
                Heap Blocks: exact=6686
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on cp_campaign_task_ap_index  (cost=0.00..135.01 rows=4366 width=0) (actual time=8.884..8.884 rows=9167 loops=4)
                    Index Cond: ((campaign_id = campaign_ports.campaign_id) AND (task_id IS NULL) AND (assigned_port = 2))

Planning time: 1.115 ms
Execution time: 2335.563 ms
```

The "campaign_phones" relation could have many rows, perhaps a million.

I don't know where to start optimizing, perhaps creating indexes or changing query structure.

Thanks.

Comment: Do many of the rows have phones with a task_id of null?
Do you have an index on campaign_phones.campaign_id?
Other things of note: casting a column usually kills the ability to index it, thus your "date" casts could be rewritten (eliminated) to use those indexes if that'd help, but it sounds like your big table is the phones table.

Comment: If `starts_at_date` and `ends_at_date` are TIMESTAMP you should compare like this `campaigns.starts_at_date >= '2018-07-08 00:00:00'::timestamp AND campaigns.ends_at_date <= '2018-07-08 00:00:00'::timestamp`. You can try adding index on `(gateway_port_id, op_mode)`. You can also combine columns `starts_at_date` / `ends_at_date` in a single `tztsrange` and then create GiST index on it to allow using the `@>` containment operator